# How to use Github as an auto-update deployment server for Joomla 3.x extension

Tags: development, plugin, update, one-click-updates, extension-update

I have gone through the two closest topics I could find here, but the auto-update extension still does not work.

I have created a 3rd party extension called paystack, that works with the Jeema SMS component [here](https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack). I need its updates to be found and be installed successfully from the Joomla Extension Manager.
So far I have tweaked the version.xml file and the manifest file itself.

I do not want to have to manually zip the file and upload to a release - I feel there has to be a way to utilize Github's autopilot archive naming convention. It would definitely be a lot easier.
Here is the latest version of my version.xml before I gave up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updates>
 <update>
    <name>plg_jsms_payment_paystack</name>
    <description>Accept payments via Master Card, Visa and Verve using Paystack. Sign up at Paystack.com for your free account.</description>
    <element>paystack</element>
    <type>plugin</type>
    <folder>jeemasms</folder>
    <client>0</client>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <infourl title="Paystack URL">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/releases/tag/1.0.1</infourl>
    <downloads>
    <downloadurl type="upgrade" format="zip">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/archive/1.0.1.zip</downloadurl>
    </downloads>
    <maintainer>Daydah Concepts</maintainer>
    <maintainerurl>https://www.daydah.com</maintainerurl>
    <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.0"/>
 </update>
 <update>
    <name>plg_jsms_payment_paystack</name>
    <description>Accept payments via Master Card, Visa and Verve using Paystack. Sign up at Paystack.com for your free account.</description>
    <element>paystack</element>
    <type>plugin</type>
    <folder>jeemasms</folder>
    <client>0</client>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <infourl title="Paystack URL">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/releases/tag/1.0.2</infourl>
    <downloads>
    <downloadurl type="upgrade" format="zip">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/archive/1.0.2.zip</downloadurl>
    </downloads>
    <maintainer>Daydah Concepts</maintainer>
    <maintainerurl>https://www.daydah.com</maintainerurl>
    <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.0"/>
 </update>
 <update>
    <name>plg_jsms_payment_paystack</name>
    <description>Accept payments via Master Card, Visa and Verve using Paystack. Sign up at Paystack.com for your free account.</description>
    <element>paystack</element>
    <type>plugin</type>
    <folder>jeemasms</folder>
    <client>0</client>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <infourl title="Paystack URL">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/releases/tag/1.0.3</infourl>
    <downloads>
    <downloadurl type="upgrade" format="zip">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/archive/1.0.3.zip</downloadurl>
    </downloads>
    <maintainer>Daydah Concepts</maintainer>
    <maintainerurl>https://www.daydah.com</maintainerurl>
    <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.0"/>
 </update>

 <update>
    <name>plg_jsms_payment_paystack</name>
    <description>Accept payments via Master Card, Visa and Verve using Paystack. Sign up at Paystack.com for your free account.</description>
    <element>paystack</element>
    <type>plugin</type>
    <folder>jeemasms</folder>
    <client>0</client>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <infourl title="Paystack URL">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/releases/tag/1.0.4</infourl>
    <downloads>
    <downloadurl type="upgrade" format="zip">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/archive/1.0.4.zip</downloadurl>
    </downloads>
    <maintainer>Daydah Concepts</maintainer>
    <maintainerurl>https://www.daydah.com</maintainerurl>
    <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.0"/>
 </update>

 <update>
    <name>plg_jsms_payment_paystack</name>
    <description>Accept payments via Master Card, Visa and Verve using Paystack. Sign up at Paystack.com for your free account.</description>
    <element>paystack</element>
    <type>plugin</type>
    <folder>jeemasms</folder>
    <client>0</client>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <infourl title="Paystack URL">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/releases/tag/paystack-1.0.6</infourl>
    <downloads>
    <downloadurl type="upgrade" format="zip">https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/archive/paystack-1.0.6.zip</downloadurl>
    </downloads>
    <maintainer>Daydah Concepts</maintainer>
    <maintainerurl>https://www.daydah.com</maintainerurl>
    <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.0"/>
 </update>
<updates>
```

As you can see, I have done a lot of testing. Versions 1.0.1 to 1.0.4 were seen by the Joomla Updates server, but it kept giving the **Error: Invalid Extension Update** as a result. The ones after 1.0.4 are not even visible.
Someone please help!
Thanks in advance!

PS: In addition, must I add an update section for every single update? I'm looking at a scenario of just replacing with the latest version, since its just a single extension.

EDIT: I have updated the version.xml file and its showing in Joomla Extension Update list. I changed the targetplatform version tag to '3.*'.

Comment: Hi @NeilRobertson. Already replied you at Stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Weblinks repo](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/weblinks)
It does exactly what you want to do.
The [updateserver](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/weblinks/blob/master/src/pkg_weblinks.xml#L28) points to the [manifest](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/weblinks/blob/master/manifest.xml) hosted on that repo.
Download packages are served from the repo as well.
Of course you need to manually update the manifest file with each release.

Comment: Thanks @Bakual but will this scenario work for plugins? I can see this is for packages. Wont I need any extra setup? And is the Priority tag optional?

Comment: It still gives the 'Invalid extension update' error. Please could you have a look at the [manifest file](https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/blob/master/paystack.xml) and the [update file](https://github.com/DaydahConcepts/paystack/blob/master/version.xml)? Maybe there is another tag am omitting by ignorance. I have removed the priority tag and the CData quotes from the manifest.

Comment: I think the update file itself needs to have an extension .zip if the format is specified as zip. I'd try that first.